# Cast unknown object to generic interface of interface (from initially explicit generic type of generic collection type of type)

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Basically I got those sample classes:

```
public interface IHasParts<TCollectionType> : where TCollectionType : ICollection
{
  TCollectionType Parts { get; set; }
}

public class CarPart
{
  //...
}

public class Car : IHasParts<List<CarPart>>
{
  public List<CarPart> Parts { get; set; }
  //...
}
```

Yes, I need to use an generic interface of `ICollection` here, because classes that implement IHasParts need different list types of `Parts` based on some hard programmed conditions.

Now I get an unknown object of i.e. `Car` and I need to cast it to the highest parent that still has the `Parts` property available:

```
Car c = new Car() {
  Parts = new List<CarPart>() {
    // ...
  }
};

object o = (object)c;

int partsCount = ((IHasParts<ICollection>)o).Parts.Count; // InvalidCastException
```

How can I do that? [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ePlLZ8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your Car class with `ICollection` instead of `List<CarPart>`, then works:

```
public class Car : IHasParts<ICollection>
{
    public ICollection Parts { get; set; }
}
```

You can still initialize your Parts with a `List<CarPart>`

Comment: Then, I can remove the generic type of `IHasParts` completely and define `Parts` of the strong interface type `ICollection`. Sure, this could be a solution, everything must use `ICollection`. Some classes that implement `IHasParts` simply uses different initialized list types, like the `ObservableCollection<>`. If I initialize `Parts` of  type `ICollection` with an `ObservableCollection` object, the subscriped events of that collection should still fire, right?

Comment: @modiX, yes, they will. And I personally think, that removing the generics all together would be the best solution in your case.

Answer (score 4):

This is a variance issue.

You're assuming that, because `List<T>` is a subtype of `ICollection`, then `IHasParts<List<T>>` must too be a subtype of `IHasParts<ICollection>`. It doesn't.

If you want `IHasParts<A>` to be a subtype of `IHasParts<B>` where `A` is a subtype of `B`, then you need to make `IHasParts` *covariant* in its type parameter `T` (using the `out` keyword).

```
public interface IHasParts<out TCollectionType> : where TCollectionType : ICollection
{
     TCollectionType Parts { get; }
}
```

For a type to be covariant, `T` can only be used in *covariant positions*: method return types, get-only property types and get-only indexers.

It can no longer be used in contravariant positions: method arguments, property/indexer setters.

Comment: You can't use "out" and property Parts with setter

Comment: @Backs Forgot to remove the setter (even though I mentioned it can't be used in settable properties), thanks!

Comment: Too bad, I need the setter there, hm. `out` keyword in this context is new for me, thanks for telling me about that.

Comment: @modiX May be implement setter as a separate method? Upd. However this still violate the "out" keyword. So this is impossible.

Comment: @Hoborg I also need to be able to serialize the whole thing. So even when this answer points the problem, it won't be a case for me.

Comment: @modiX if you're worried about serialization, you might get away with declaring the setter on the implementing class, but not on the covariant interface. Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/53wlXx

Answer (score 1):

Add an abstract class to take care of specifying the ICollection type.  Declare your code something like this:

```
public interface IHasParts
{
    ICollection Parts { get; }
}

public abstract class HasParts<TCollectionType, TPartType> : IHasParts where TCollectionType : ICollection
{

    public TCollectionType Parts;


    ICollection IHasParts.Parts { get { return this.Parts; } }

}

public class CarPart
{
    //...
}

public class Car : HasParts<List<CarPart>, CarPart>
{
    protected void AddParts()
    {
        this.Parts.Add(new CarPart());
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Here is an updated version of your DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/O3JZgc